# Uploading to cloud storage with API, RequestException

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-dotnet-client

Can anyone tell me why this code gets a request exception?

```
Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object obj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object();
obj.Bucket = "testbucket1817";
obj.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";
obj.SelfLink = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file";
obj.Name = "filename";
Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertRequest uploadrequest = new ObjectsResource.InsertRequest(storagecredentials, obj, "testbucket1817");
uploadrequest.Execute();
```

When run I get this error message-

```
Required [400]
Errors [
    Message[Required] Location[ - ] Reason[required] Domain[global]
    Message[Required] Location[ - ] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]
```

I'm not sure about the selflink thing or the content type (for an xml file) but there's nothing anywhere that actually says how this should be done.
Thanks anyone

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough the message just said RequestException I tried to find anything more helpful but the best i got was _HttpStatus=Bad Request_

Comment: just added the error message it doesn't look too telling

Comment: Try first to upload a text file, just (text/plain). Then, after it works try to upload a content like binary/octet-stream. I think you can ignore the SelfLink either way.

Comment: @peleyal I'm not sure in which property of the body I should specify the data that's being uploaded if not selflink. This is all my code for the uploading

Comment: Do you want to upload a file to Storage? If so, you can take a look in the Drive demo - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Drive.Sample/Program.cs?repo=samples#119

Answer (score 1):

*InsertMediaUpload* seems to work fine. Don't know what the difference is from *InsertRequest* other than I can figure out where to put the data with *InsertMediaUpload*. So whatever file you want to upload, just set a stream as `File.Open(yourfile, FileMode.Open)` and set an object like I did in the question.

```
Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload uploadmedia = new 
    ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(ss, object, "bucketname", fileStream, "binary/octet-stream");
```

that sets up the upload and then `uploadmedia.Upload()` executes.
Thanks everyone!
Ross